# Query string filtering by custom field

Tags: sharepoint-designer, custom, query-string

i added a custom action in sharepoint designer which is a url link to a document library. On this document library page i have added a query sting filter webpart, to filter data based on a list ID. I named the Query String Parameter Name for the webpart filter "R_ID" which is shown in the url example below. Also note "{ItemID} in the url is a token used to get the id of the current list item.

(`https://mysite.sharepoint.com/site1/Test_Profile_Page/Profile.aspx?R_ID={ItemId}`.

The url link above works fine but i would like to filter it based on an email address value instead of an List ID value. I have searched and there doesn't seem to be an option to use a custom field in the url and pass this as a query parameter. What i would like to do is shown below in example. first i change the name of the query string parmeter name from "R_ID" to EmailID and then change the token {ItemID} to the name of the email address field in this example i will use email_address

```
https://mysite.sharepoint.com/site1/Test_Profile_Page/Profile.aspx?EmailID={email_address}
```

This does not work i would just like to know if it is possible and if i am going about it the right way , thanks

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Edit the page and click on "Query String (URL) Filter" webpart dropdown.

Click on connections - Send Filter values to - 'Document Library'. In the consumer field name, select the 'EmailAddress' field.

Query String parameter can be changed from R_ID to Email in Webpart properties.

Comment: The problem is with the custom action url link i created in sharepoint designer i'm not sure if you can use it to get information from a custom string field named email_address " https://mysite.sharepoint.com/site1/Test_Profile_Page/Profile.aspx?EmailID={email_address} " The url link to grab the list item ID works fine but that is because the token ( {ItemId} ) is used